# $H, K$ subgroups of the same order and $H$ and $K$ intersect nontrivially

Tags: group-theory

> If $G$ is a group, can it have $2$ proper subgroups, $H$ and $K$ of the same order and $H\cap K\neq\emptyset$

I think it is possible if $G$ is infinite, if $G=\mathbb Z$ then

$H=2\mathbb Z$, $K=3\mathbb Z$

There is a relation to the exercise below (apologize for the long text), I mean if instead of $3$, it were a non-prime, the argumentation would fail, or not ? (because we make use of ''Since every non-identity element lies $\underline{\text{in exactly one}}$ such order-$3$ subgroup'')

[image])

Answer (score 2):

Since the intersection of two subgroups at least contains the identity, I assume you menat that $H\cap K$ should be nontrivial (instead of empty).
Easy examples are that $A\oplus A\oplus B$ contains $A\oplus B$ as subgroup in two ways (that are distinct if $A$ is nontrivial) and both contain the same $B$. So if $B$ is also nontrivial you have your example.

Comment: is the symbol, the external direct product ?

Comment: @inequal Actually, the direct sum, but that doesn't matter with finitely many summands/factors. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ and look at the subgroups $\{(0, 0), (1, 0)\}$ and $\{(0, 0), (0, 1)\}$.

It is important to note that this really comes down to finding two subgroups that are of the same order but are distinct since any two subgroups will always intersect at the identity.

Comment: Of course the identity is excluded, I'll edit the qeustion, thanks